# Apache log filled with Proxy errors

Tags: ssl, apache2, server-side-attacks

I have a website hosting in AWS, recently server become super slow, i checked apache error log, the log keep growing, repeated, ad infinitum like: e-commerce, games, porn etc.

Is someone attacking my site? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.331868 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885809760000] [client 27.186.196.160:22037] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL auth.riotgames.com:443 (scheme 'auth.riotgames.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.332579 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3104:tid 139884786341632] [client 18.166.178.184:57677] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL signup.live.com:443 (scheme 'signup.live.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.332744 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3104:tid 139884769556224] [client 58.177.48.72:53483] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL signup.live.com:443 (scheme 'signup.live.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.491080 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3104:tid 139884769556224] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 178.32.47.166:443 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.491142 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3104:tid 139884769556224] [client 23.19.68.34:43214] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.labaladedesgnomes.be
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.491449 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3104:tid 139884769556224] [client 101.80.205.11:60772] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL list.tmall.com:443 (scheme 'list.tmall.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.491640 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3104:tid 139884769556224] [client 103.195.184.13:62294] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL api.sendgrid.com:443 (scheme 'api.sendgrid.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.527905 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885809760000] [client 101.89.166.49:58293] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL wq.jd.com:443 (scheme 'wq.jd.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:20.528202 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885809760000] [client 27.26.237.105:18957] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL fr.elsword.gameforge.com:443 (scheme 'fr.elsword.gameforge.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:22.379491 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3019:tid 139884845057792] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:22.379546 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3019:tid 139884845057792] [client 62.171.165.204:47910] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427476 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885675542272] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427472 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3048:tid 139885272889088] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 64.131.90.213:443 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427527 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885675542272] [client 62.171.165.204:39032] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427540 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3048:tid 139885272889088] [client 23.19.68.139:57626] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.econometricsociety.org
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427665 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3076:tid 139884752770816] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427684 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3076:tid 139884752770816] [client 62.171.164.115:35578] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.427834 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3048:tid 139885272889088] [client 46.29.163.30:53098] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL 13.228.133.192:80 (scheme '13.228.133.192'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.428062 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3048:tid 139885272889088] [client 150.136.126.35:58807] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL www.youporn.com:443 (scheme 'www.youporn.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:24.428474 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139884752770816] [client 42.2.159.101:62645] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL signup.live.com:443 (scheme 'signup.live.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:28.523473 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 2961:tid 139885289641728] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:28.523540 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2961:tid 139885289641728] [client 62.171.164.115:56558] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:28.684557 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 2961:tid 139885289641728] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 178.32.47.166:443 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:28.684615 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2961:tid 139885289641728] [client 23.19.68.34:53700] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.labaladedesgnomes.be
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619459 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3019:tid 139885532931840] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 8.210.74.48:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619460 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619514 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3019:tid 139885532931840] [client 193.160.96.165:48228] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: hs.fw1688.net
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619529 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 62.171.164.115:46470] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619691 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 2960:tid 139885776189184] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 5.189.135.137:443 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619716 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2960:tid 139885776189184] [client 23.19.65.214:33810] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.muenchner-kreis.de
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619781 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3019:tid 139885532931840] [client 58.177.48.72:53708] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL signup.live.com:443 (scheme 'signup.live.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619876 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 222.142.231.20:55008] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL auth-ac.my.games:443 (scheme 'auth-ac.my.games'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.619966 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3019:tid 139885532931840] [client 101.91.214.196:62925] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL wq.jd.com:443 (scheme 'wq.jd.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.620037 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 101.91.243.5:59361] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL wq.jd.com:443 (scheme 'wq.jd.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.620192 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 149.129.106.5:39244] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL httpbin.org:443 (scheme 'httpbin.org'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.620482 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 39.106.19.24:33266] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL xueqiu.com:443 (scheme 'xueqiu.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.620642 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3076:tid 139885776189184] [client 47.100.247.177:52758] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL api.nasdaq.com:443 (scheme 'api.nasdaq.com'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.706185 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3076:tid 139884761163520] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 193.160.32.21:60408] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server q.eznizvj.cn:80
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:32.706237 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3076:tid 139884761163520] [client 193.160.32.21:60408] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by http:/q.eznizvj.cn/mop/index?token=7sJXWiXFTbyupWHD/
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667472 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885272889088] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667472 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3019:tid 139885658756864] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 64.131.90.213:443 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667523 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885272889088] [client 144.91.113.234:48744] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667534 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3019:tid 139885658756864] [client 23.19.68.139:34420] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: www.econometricsociety.org
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667649 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3019:tid 139884736018176] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667681 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3019:tid 139884736018176] [client 62.171.165.204:41448] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667752 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885239318272] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 218.78.34.99:80 (*) failed
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667765 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3104:tid 139885239318272] [client 144.91.113.234:57262] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 218.78.34.99
[Tue Dec 08 15:10:34.667904 2020] [proxy:warn] [pid 3019:tid 139885658756864] [client 121.56.157.178:52898] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL production-game-api.sekai.colorfulpalette.org:443 (scheme 'production-game-api.sekai.colorfulpalette.org'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Answer (score 0):

No one is attacking your host but you didn't provide any useful information (like the configuration) other than the errors, to give any feedback.